# How to re-edit /system file to reboot phone?

Tags: reboot, boot

How does one re-set or edit the /system/build.prop, when changes kept it from booting up again? Rooted Optimus.

Comment: What were the changes you made?

Comment: bad dalvik.vm.heapsize

Comment: Which phone do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebooting into recovery and connecting to the phone via ADB:

`adb devices`

It should give a message like this:

```
List of devices attached  
01234565ABCDEFG        recovery
```

You can then copy the file off the phone:

`adb pull /system/build.prop c:\build.prop`

You can now edit it in any text editor (recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) because it will preserve the Unix style line endings,) and then copy it back to the phone:

`adb push c:\build.prop /system/build.prop`

If the issue was indeed within that file, the phone should boot now.

Comment: reboot recovery how?

Comment: Depends on the phone; it's usually different for each model.  Usually you shut it off (pull the battery if you can't any other way) and then turn it on while holding a button or a combination of buttons.  This should be in the manual.  If not, try a Google search for "recovery mode" for your phone's model.

Comment: Ok, phone recovery doesn't seem to have done anything, just showed a different boot animation.

Comment: Did you have a custom recovery installed to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

You restore the backup you made before editing such a sensitive file.

```
rm build.prop
cp yourbackupbuild.prop build.prop
```

If you didn't have the foresight to make a backup, then I guess you can ask for someone with the same phone/software version to send you theirs.

Comment: I wasn't able to su, it gave error in adb shell

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore the factory firmware using the instructions [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=875881&page=4). Worked with no problem on Windows 7. :)

I guess this is why we should use custom-recovery like Clockworkmod?